# jQuery Chaining/Efficiency Advice

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari

Ok, before you review the code below, I know that it is AWFUL. It's redundant and bloated and I am not asking for anyone to fix it :)

I am wondering what I need to study in order to fix it on my own. I'm working on a small project for my daughter, an interactive multiplication table that she can view in Mobile Safari.

I want to highlight the cells that lead to a selected number. So, I created this and I'm sharing it because I want to improve it, but I don't have enough knowledge yet.

What principles do I need to study to improve this kind of functionality?

You can see the whole thing here: http://dandenney.com/dev/jasmultiplication

The 100 (10 x 10) is an example of what I am trying to achieve, but I want to do it for every number:

```
// This starts base functionality of highlighting the involved numbers, 10x10=100
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tenxten").hover(function () {
            $("td").addClass("non-choice");
            }, function () {
            $("td").removeClass("non-choice");
    });
    $(".tenxten").hover(function () {
            $(".twoxten, .threexten, .fourxten, .fivexten, .sixxten, .sevenxten,  .eightxten, .ninexten").addClass("vertical-trail");
            }, function () {
            $(".twoxten, .threexten, .fourxten, .fivexten, .sixxten, .sevenxten, .eightxten, .ninexten").removeClass("vertical-trail");
    });
    $(".tenxten").hover(function () {
            $(".tenxtwo, .tenxthree, .tenxfour, .tenxfive, .tenxsix, .tenxseven, .tenxeight, .tenxnine").addClass("horizontal-trail");
            }, function () {
            $(".tenxtwo, .tenxthree, .tenxfour, .tenxfive, .tenxsix, .tenxseven, .tenxeight, .tenxnine").removeClass("horizontal-trail");
    });
    $(".tenxten").hover(function () {
            $(".vertical-ten, .horizontal-ten").addClass("choice");
            }, function () {
            $(".vertical-ten, .horizontal-ten").removeClass("choice");
    });
});
```

Comment: I haven't studied your code carefully, but I think you will probably be able to make it more elegant by using `.data()` method, which allows you to store arbitrary data with matched elements. See http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the 10x10 effect you can use the row you're hovering, the index of the `<td>` in it, and [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) for both to get the effect on the right cells, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#multiplication").delegate("tr:gt(0) td:not(:first-child)", "hover", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("choice").prevAll().toggleClass("horizontal-trail")
     .end().closest('tr').prevAll().find('td:nth-child('+($(this).index()+1)+')')
                                   .toggleClass('vertical-trail');
  });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Uk4vp/1/), this applies the horizontal class by just using [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) to get the previous cells in the row.  Then using [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) we go back to `$(this)` (the currently hovered cell), go up to it's `<tr>` using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), again get all rows before that using [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and getting the cells at the same index in them using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), then adding or removing the class on those cells.

Since you're just toggling on and off, you can use one hover function which maps to both `mouseneter` and `mouseleave` combined with [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).  The [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) use is to have *one* hover handler here, instead of 100.

The initial selector `"tr:gt(0) td:not(:first-child)"` is saying not the first row, and not the left most cells in other rows, so this prevents the main numbers from executing this function, so it'll only happen in the table.

Comment: Wow ! Awesome stuff... hats off, sir... :)

Comment: Awesome!!! I'm sorry I'm so behind on responding, I thought I had it set for email notifications. 

Thank you, there is much to learn from this.

Comment: @Dan - Welcome :) Be sure to accept an answer on this and future questions if it resolves your problem :)

Comment: Awesome, I accepted it. This is a great example of understanding the technology that you're using. 22 lines for one number replaces by 6 lines for 81 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Commendable project. :)

Chaining would not necessarily affect the performance/efficiency, but the selectors would, I suppose. One element could have more than one class name even at design time, so I would lay down the classes on the matrix carefully, so I would get the desired effect in less number of `hover` than what you have now. Like all rows would have a common class each, all columns would have their common class each etc.